# What is the best way to insert data into joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, insert

This is my table structure which i am using for the sql query:

```
SONGS         MEDIA
id            id
track         song_id
artist        source
added_on      url
```

How can i insert a song (track,artist,added_on,source,url)?
MEDIA.SONG_ID needs to be the correct SONGS.ID

`MEDIA.ID and SONGS.ID` are both primary and auto increment.

Does anybody knows how to do this?

Comment: You cannot insert data into 2 tables at the same time, MySQL does not offer that feature. (There is a `INSERT ALL` command, but which is not available in MySQL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard SQL, you would use a transaction and the `nextval` and `currval` functions on the ID sequence:

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO songs VALUES(nextval('songs_id_sequence'), ...);
INSERT INTO media VALUES(nextval('media_id_sequence'), currval('songs_id_sequence'), ...);
COMMIT
```

Comment: nextval is sql funcion?

Comment: It is in the SQL standard.

Comment: but MySQL doenst really follow the SQL standard... nextval isn't an function within the MySQL database..

Answer (score 0):

1) First option

you can insert into SONGS, getting song id and after it insert into MEDIA
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

2) Second option

Using updatable view (built on top of this two tables)
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/view-updatability.html

3) Third option

Using stored procedure with logic similar as first option